Is there a way to loop through two lists in VBA, copying from one to the other but never copying a duplicate value?
I have two sheets. Sheet 1) Mass Slot List, Sheet 2) Location Storage Types
I need to go through roughly 15,000 rows in sheet 1 and use a specific code in the AQ column (which could be one of 39 codes like 1A8, 5K2, 2C12, etc.) to look through sheet 2 for rows that have the same code in column B. The information that I need is in Column A of sheet 2 and must be moved to column C of sheet 1.
The other requirements are: Sheet 2's Column C must = "L", Column D must = "No" and Column E must equal Sheet 1's Column A.
The same result from column A on sheet 2 cannot be used twice, but must move down to the next result meeting the criteria.
The end result that I'm trying to achieve is that I go through each row in sheet 1 and fill column C with a different result from Sheet 2's column A that matches all of the criteria listed above.
Edit #4: Rewrote question to be, hopefully, more accurate.
Set msl = Worksheets("Mass Slot List")
Set lst = Worksheets("Location Storage Types")

aRow = wsl.Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row
bRow = lst.Range("A120000").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To aRow

    If msl.Range("AQ" & x) = "1A8" Then
        For y = 1 To bRow
            If lst.Range("B" & y) = "1A8" And lst.Range("C" & y) = "L" And lst.Range("D" & y) = "No" And          lst.Range("E" & y) = msl.Range("A" & x) Then
                msl.Range("C" & x) = lst.Range("A" & y)
                
                Exit For
            End If
        Next y
    End If
Next x

I tried the above code, but it simply ran for a few minutes and force closed excel.
I'm not married to the code above, it's just what my limited knowledge can produce.
Edit #1: Got some constructive criticism in the comments.
Sheet 2 looks like this:

Sheet 1 looks like this:

Edit #2: A link to a smaller, more simplified version of the file (Updated x2):
https://fastupload.io/8eee9b2bd4d9a6d3
Edit #3:Tim's Solution First Pass

"crashed my Excel" looks like what exactly? - do you mean it just takes a long time to run, or it actually crashes?

You have 4 If tests in one line there - your code will run faster if you nest those each as individual tests.  As it stands now, even if the first test fails the other 3 will still be run, which means 3 additional cell reads per iteration.

...and you will see a much better performance if you first read your data into arrays, and loop over those arrays instead of reading cell-by-cell from the worksheets.

Last comment!  It would help your question a lot to show some sample data - relevant columns only.  Also you could explain a little more what you mean by "I have no way for it to not create duplicates" - what exactly is a duplicate in this case?

Please include enough of a data sample as text which can be copy/pasted and the expected results from that data sample. As it is, we can only make general statements such as those recommendations by @TimWilliams to speed things up, but not much more.

@TimWilliams What I mean by crashing Excel is that Excel quits responding and I have to close the program. I did get it to find one answer using my criteria, after I opened the program back up, so I'm on the right path I think. I just need a more efficient way to do it. Also, I edited the post and added some data to hopefully give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

@RonRosenfeld Hello Ron, I added a small sample file to the bottom of the post to hopefully make the problem clearer. Let me know what else might help.

@Hobis Your link is broken. And your screenshots don't show original data and results.

@RonRosenfeld I changed the link and there were no original results. My attempt was a complete failure.

@Hobis I give up. Your current download doesn't work for me. Something about my account not authorized to open this workbook. Hopefully someone else will be able to assist you.

Your hosted file has some kind of information rights management applied to it, so likely no-one will either be able (or want to) open it.

@TimWilliams You're 100% correct, I completely forgot to remove that before I uploaded it. Updated a new link with the file not under DRM.

@RonRosenfeld I apologize Ron, it had DRM on it as Tim pointed out earlier. I had forgotten to remove it. Removed the DRM, uploaded the file and edited in a new link.

Compiled but not tested: based on your posted code.
Sub AssignStorage()
    
    Dim msl As Worksheet, lst As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, vHK
    Dim lrMsl As Long, lrLst As Long, id As String, mslA, c As Range
    Dim arrMslAQ, arrLstAtoE, x As Long, y As Long, rngTypes As Range
    Dim t
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set msl = wb.Worksheets("Mass Slot List")
    Set lst = wb.Worksheets("Location Storage Types")
    
    lrMsl = msl.Cells(msl.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lrLst = lst.Cells(lst.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'read data into arrays for faster access
    arrMslAQ = msl.Range("AQ1:AQ" & lrMsl) 'col AQ only
    arrLstAtoE = lst.Range("A1:E" & lrLst) 'cols A to E
    
    Set rngTypes = TypesList()
    t = Timer
    For Each c In rngTypes.Cells 'loop over storage types
        id = c.Value
        For x = 2 To lrMsl
            mslA = msl.Cells(x, "A").Value 'only need to read this once...
            If arrMslAQ(x, 1) = id Then
                For y = 1 To lrLst
                    If arrLstAtoE(y, 2) = id Then
                        If arrLstAtoE(y, 3) = "L" Then
                            If arrLstAtoE(y, 4) = "No" Then
                                vHK = arrLstAtoE(y, 5)
                                If IsError(vHK) Then vHK = "Error" 'some of your H/K values are errors
                                If vHK = mslA Then
                                    'update and exit
                                    msl.Cells(x, "C").Value = arrLstAtoE(y, 1)
                                    arrLstAtoE(y, 4) = "Yes" 'flag as used
                                    'ideally you're also updating the Mass Slot List here?
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next y
            End If
        Next x
    Next c 'next storege type id
    MsgBox "Done in " & Round(Timer - t, 0) & " sec"

End Sub

'return a range with all of the distinct storage types
' These are stored in a listobject named "TypesList" on sheet "Lists"
Function TypesList() As Range
    Set TypesList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lists").ListObjects("TypesList"). _
                       ListColumns("StorageTypes").DataBodyRange
End Function


There are other faster ways to approach this, but this is closest to what you already have.

I really appreciate it. I ran the code and it went very quickly and assigned a location to every part with the 1A8 type, but it assigned the same location to every part with that type. The only exception being once it reached row 11975, when it changed to a different location and began assigning that same location to the rest of the locations. So I ended up with two different locations with a few thousand items assigned to each. Trying to add a picture for reference.

The first location which meets the criteria will always be the one which gets assigned.  It's not clear from your post what should happen instead.  Is there some max number of times the same location can be used?  Only once?

My apologies Tim, yes, each location may only have one part assigned to it.  I added a picture of the results of your response to the bottom of the post. Is there also a way to make "id" a variable for a list of different codes? Ex: "1A8, 5K2" etc? I promise I'm not trying to be difficult, I'm just incredibly new. I've never used stack overflow before, just browsed previous questions.

So should the code be updating the "Already used" column to "Yes" when a location gets assigned?

I didn't know that was an option, but if it helps then yes. Currently it's just an IF/VLOOKUP formula that's referencing yet another sheet.

See edit to add arrLstAtoE(y, 4) = "Yes" 'flag as used

I can help you off-line if you're still having problems, but you'd need to share your workbook via (eg) email for that to work.

It worked like a charm Tim! Thank you so much! Is there a way to make "id" a variable that could also contain the other 38 unique codes that it would be looking for? how would I reach you offline?

Code updated above to add looping over all listed id codes.
